# remove value from mongoDB array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, stack, mean

hi i am trying to remove a value from mongoDB but instead of removing a specific value the code is deleting all users from the schema lol.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../../models/UserModel');

module.exports.unfollow = function(req, res){

    var thefollowee = req.body.followee;
    var thefollower = req.body.follower;


    User.find({_id: thefollower}).remove({following: thefollowee}).exec();

    User.find({_id: thefollowee}).remove({followers: thefollower}).exec();

    res.json({ message: 'Unfollowed'});




};
```

the followee is pointing to the id of the person being followed,
the follower is pointing to the id of the user who follows the followee.

Comment: I just saw your answer pop up, but you might also use mongoose's [findOneAndRemove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndRemove) method.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i got it by using the $pull method

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../../models/UserModel');

module.exports.unfollow = function(req, res){

    var thefollowee = req.body.followee;
    var thefollower = req.body.follower;


        User.findByIdAndUpdate(thefollowee, { $pull: { followers: req.body.follower }}, function (err, user) {

            if (err)

            return handleError(err);

        });

        User.findByIdAndUpdate(thefollower, { $pull: { following: req.body.followee }}, function (err, user) {

            if (err)

            return handleError(err);

        });

    res.json({ message: 'Unfollowed'});




};
```